# Is it possible to get all users from Azure Active Directory to another domain databse automatically on event?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I tried with Graph API with/without user, and retrieved users list. But it is manual process. I am new to Azure Active Directory, can anybody helps me regarding this?

Comment: Hi, may I know you want to do the get user operation on which event ?

Comment: scheduler event or crone job, on another domain i will fire an even on every 24 hrs, so i can sync my db with active directory users.

Comment: May I know if your problem was solved ? If the solution provided below helps your problem, could you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Comment: @HuryShen Thank you for your help, I am trying it.

Comment: If still have any problem, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, sure and thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, provide two solutions for your reference.

**solution 1:**

You can use a [timer trigger function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp) and set the cron expression as `0 0 0 * * *` to trigger the function every day(at 0 am). Then request the graph api in your function code.

**solution 2:**

You can also use [logic app recurrence trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence) and set it triggered every day.
[image]

Then use "[HTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#add-an-http-action)" action to request for the access token.
[image]

Now use "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action to parse the response body from the "HTTP" action above.
[image]

The schema in "Parse JSON" should be:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "access_token": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "expires_in": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "ext_expires_in": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "token_type": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

After that, we can add another "HTTP" action to request the graph api (with the access token from "Parse JSON" above)
[image]